# SSRS: Report column populated in VisStudio, empty on server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

So I'm working on a simple SSRS report.  When I preview the report in Visual Studio 2010, it behaves as expected.  However, when I view the report on the server, the column is empty.

**What I've Tried that Hasn't Worked:**

Deleting and Redeploying
Moving columns in the report around

Below are two pictures of the Visual Studio, and the SSRS Server.

[image: Correct output in VS 2010]

[image: Incorrect output in SSRS]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the data source set up correctly on the Report Server? If you export the report to excel does it have data ?

Comment: Does your database have any kind of column-level security set up?  And are you executing your report with the exact same credentials/security on VS as you are on the server?

Comment: @HolmesIV No, there is no data if I export to Excel.

Comment: @DeadZone No, there is no column level security as we aren't that advanced.

Comment: I am assuming you have closed your browser and reopened ? I know SSRS has a nasty way of caching results which can be annoying.

Comment: @HolmesIV Yes, I have fully closed and re-opened.  I've also restarted my machine in the meantime.  Also, the report is reflecting changes in column order, but it isn't populating that one column no matter where it appears.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the same **Datasource** in Report Manger as you are in Visual Studio? Are you referencing a View?

Comment: Use the SQL Profiler to intercept the call that is being made from SSRS in Visual Studio and compare it to the one being made from SSRS on the Report Server.  Do they match?  If so, the problem is likely on the SQL Server.  If not, then the problem is likely with the report or report server.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably doing a left or right join and the data on the server does not have matching information on one of the tables. In other words the data on the server is not the same as that the BIDS(Visual Studio) points to.

Copy the sql that is the dataset of the report and run it on Management Studio pointing to production and you will likely discover that you are getting blank columns just like when you run the report from SSRS>